# update a list html whenever a variable changed

Tags: angular

I have an issue. I have this code inside a function, this code returns a boolean when the function is called
 `col.transformed`

````
           if (col.value.name === this.selectedColumn) {
             console.log('rrrrrr',compilerequest)
             if(dataFiltered.requestParsed!="\"\""){
             col.transformed = true;
             this.formControlValue = "";
             this.selectedColumn = "";
             console.log('ghhh',this.selectedColumn,this.formControlValue,col.transformed)
           }
             else{
             col.transformed=false;
             console.log('jjjjjjj',col.value.name)
           }
         }
         });```
and in the template i display the element if ```col.transformed==true```
```<tr *ngFor="let transf of cols">
               <td *ngIf="transf?.transformed" style="height: 47px;cursor: pointer;padding-left: 42px;padding-top: 15px;display: inline-flex;margin-bottom: 5px;">
                   <div class="label"> {{transf?.value?.name}} </div>
                   <span class="label2">{{transf?.value?.type}}</span>
               </td>
           </tr>```
but when a element is displayed however the value of ```col.trformed``` is changed to false,the list displayed is not updated,how can i update it whenever the value ```col.transformed``` is changed.
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then I assume you would like your HTML content to change/update after your variable was changed?

I would recommend using Angular built-in change detection.

Imports:

```
    import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Component:

```
    @Component({
       changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
```

Constructor:

```
    public changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef
```

...and at the end of your function you should use markForCheck to mark possible changes

```
    this.changeDetection.markForCheck();
```

Hope it helps you!

Regards